# Choosing value from drop-down in DOM (Katalon Studio)

Tags: reactjs, dom, katalon-studio

I have a problem with some div with drop-down in DOM (I create test in Katalon Studio). 
I choose values through JavaScriptExecutor, but finally the fields are resetting.

The biggest problem is that we have 3 input fields with the same name, I have no idea how to properly call them, and then select a specific value later.

And HTML code:

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
      <h6>Date of birth</h6>
      <p>Your date of birth will be used for age verification purposes only</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="custom-select-checkout ">
         <input class="select-selected" value="May" readonly="">
         <div class="select-items select-hide">
            <div>January</div>
            <div>February</div>
            <div>March</div>
            <div>April</div>
            <div>May</div>
            <div>June</div>
            <div>July</div>
            <div>August</div>
            <div>September</div>
            <div>October</div>
            <div>November</div>
            <div>December</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="custom-select-checkout ">
         <input class="select-selected" value="Day" readonly="">
         <div class="select-items select-hide">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>11</div>
            <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div>
            <div>14</div>
            <div>15</div>
            <div>16</div>
            <div>17</div>
            <div>18</div>
            <div>19</div>
            <div>20</div>
            <div>21</div>
            <div>22</div>
            <div>23</div>
            <div>24</div>
            <div>25</div>
            <div>26</div>
            <div>27</div>
            <div>28</div>
            <div>29</div>
            <div>30</div>
            <div>31</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="custom-select-checkout ">
         <input class="select-selected" value="Year" readonly="">
         <div class="select-items select-hide">
            <div>2018</div>
            <div>2017</div>
            <div>2016</div>
            <div>2015</div>
            <div>2014</div>
            <div>2013</div>
            <div>2012</div>
            <div>2011</div>
            <div>2010</div>
            <div>2009</div>
            <div>2008</div>
            <div>2007</div>
            <div>2006</div>
            <div>2005</div>
            <div>2004</div>
            <div>2003</div>
            <div>2002</div>
            <div>2001</div>
            <div>2000</div>
            <div>1999</div>
            <div>1998</div>
            <div>1997</div>
            <div>1996</div>
            <div>1995</div>
            <div>1994</div>
            <div>1993</div>
            <div>1992</div>
            <div>1991</div>
            <div>1990</div>
            <div>1989</div>
            <div>1988</div>
            <div>1987</div>
            <div>1986</div>
            <div>1985</div>
            <div>1984</div>
            <div>1983</div>
            <div>1982</div>
            <div>1981</div>
            <div>1980</div>
            <div>1979</div>
            <div>1978</div>
            <div>1977</div>
            <div>1976</div>
            <div>1975</div>
            <div>1974</div>
            <div>1973</div>
            <div>1972</div>
            <div>1971</div>
            <div>1970</div>
            <div>1969</div>
            <div>1968</div>
            <div>1967</div>
            <div>1966</div>
            <div>1965</div>
            <div>1964</div>
            <div>1963</div>
            <div>1962</div>
            <div>1961</div>
            <div>1960</div>
            <div>1959</div>
            <div>1958</div>
            <div>1957</div>
            <div>1956</div>
            <div>1955</div>
            <div>1954</div>
            <div>1953</div>
            <div>1952</div>
            <div>1951</div>
            <div>1950</div>
            <div>1949</div>
            <div>1948</div>
            <div>1947</div>
            <div>1946</div>
            <div>1945</div>
            <div>1944</div>
            <div>1943</div>
            <div>1942</div>
            <div>1941</div>
            <div>1940</div>
            <div>1939</div>
            <div>1938</div>
            <div>1937</div>
            <div>1936</div>
            <div>1935</div>
            <div>1934</div>
            <div>1933</div>
            <div>1932</div>
            <div>1931</div>
            <div>1930</div>
            <div>1929</div>
            <div>1928</div>
            <div>1927</div>
            <div>1926</div>
            <div>1925</div>
            <div>1924</div>
            <div>1923</div>
            <div>1922</div>
            <div>1921</div>
            <div>1920</div>
            <div>1919</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select that exactly same way as you do manually like

1. Click the select input value
2. Wait for dropdown to be visible
3. Select the particular value

Based on your html, your Katalon script will be like this.

```
TestObject selectBox = new TestObject('SelectBox').addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, "input.select-selected")
WebUI. click(selectBox)

TestObject dropdownValue = new TestObject('DropDownValue').addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[contains(@class, 'select-items')]/div[contains(text(), 'May')]")
WebUI.waitForElementVisible(dropdownValue, 30)
WebUI.click(dropdownValue)
```

Comment: I think your xpath of dropdownValue pointed to the main div, not the Month div that  will be clicked

Comment: Yeap. Updated it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thank you guys, but I have an error - Unable to click on object 'DropDownValue' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible.

I think this problem is due to the fact that the input "select-selected" appears on the page up to 4 times and we have to refer to the index of this input (or maybe you have other solutions)

Comment: Add complete html of the select box with parent tags of current input. Imput may not be right element to be click.

Comment: When the selectBox box is clicked in first line, is the drop-down appear?

Comment: I added HTML of this div and the selectBox was not clicked

Comment: do u get any error for selectbox click? Based on your html, the first select box should  be clicked. Try this css  "input.select-selected[value='Month']" for clicking month select box

Comment: @Weirdo_Mrln: it will be help if you could give the url to the control. There are important thing we need to clarify: the html code you pasted there might be in html before the dropdown list is present. If you click on the textbox, the drop-down appear and the html DOM will be different. It can be a new selection, a new dialog, etc. This is the actual place you need to perform action, not the html code before you click.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create custom keyword for later use. I have an example of dropdown list in Jira system at https://github.com/katalon-studio-samples/tips-and-tricks/blob/master/Keywords/com/jira/components/JSelect.groovy.